# Using "[[ ]]" notation for reference class methods

Tags: r, reference-class

While experimenting with the new reference classes in R I noticed some odd behaviour if you use the "[[ ]]" notation for methods (X[["doSomething"]] instead of X$doSomething). This notation works for fields, but I initially thought it wouldn't work for methods until I found that if you execute "class(X$doSomething)" you can then use "[[ ]]" afterwards. The simple example below illustrates the point.

```
setRefClass("Number", 
  fields = list(
    value = "numeric"
  ),
  methods = list(
    addOne = function() {
      value <<- value + 1
    }
  )
)

X <- new("Number", value = 1)

X[['value']]         # 1

X[["addOne"]]()      # Error: attempt to apply non-function
class(X[["addOne"]]) # NULL

class(X$addOne)      # "refMethodDef"

# Now the following works!
X[["addOne"]]()      # sets X$value = 2
class(X[["addOne"]]) # "refMethodDef"
```

The reason I encountered this is because I want to group my objects together in a list and create an "applyMethod" function which applies a specified method on each of the objects within. Therefore, I need to specify the method as a string. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Reference classes are supposed to be instantiated as `.A = setRefClass(<...>); .A$new()`. Is `[[` meant to be used for member access? From `?ReferenceClasses` the API is `$`. Might as well color within the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a class

```
.A <-
    setRefClass("A",
                fields=list(x="numeric"),
                methods=list(foo=function() x))
```

If I had an instance `a` and wanted to construct a call to the 'foo' method using '$' I could

```
eval(substitute(a$FUN(), list(FUN="foo")))
```

So I'll create a class `Alist` that is meant to have a list of elements of class `A` (this could be enforced programmatically), and that has a `.delegate` method that'll apply an arbitrary method to all elements of the list. I'll then add a method that delegates `foo`.

```
.delegate <- function(FUN, ...)
{
    lapply(elts, function(elt, ...) {
        eval(substitute(elt$FUN(...), list(FUN=FUN, ...)))
    })
}

.Alist <-
    setRefClass("Alist",
                fields=list(elts="list"),
                methods=list(
                  initialize = function(...) callSuper(elts=list(...)),
                  .delegate = .delegate,
                  foo=function() .delegate("foo")))
```

And then use it

```
> aList <- .Alist$new(.A$new(x=1), .A$new(x=2))
> aList$foo()
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

basically R5 ref class does not cache the method until it is necessary. This is probably a kind of delayed evaluation.

And the caching takes place when you access the method via `$`.
So, AFAIK, there is no way to access the method via [[string]]

But you can find a workaround using .dollarForEnvRefClass like this:

```
> X <- new("Number", value = 1)
> ls(X@.xData)
[1] "value" # no methods named "addOne" before caching
> X[["addOne"]]
NULL
> methods:::.dollarForEnvRefClass(X, "addOne") # cache it
Class method definition for method addOne()
function () 
{
    value <<- value + 1
}
<environment: 0x116a4aa00>
> ls(X@.xData)
[1] "addOne" "value"  # you can find it
> X$value # value is 1
[1] 1
> X[["addOne"]]() # call the method
> X$value  # the method works
[1] 2
```

if you are interested in more detail, see the implementation:
http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/methods/R/refClass.R

Maybe there is more straightforward way.

Comment: I believe the "R5" term is not the proper way to refer to Reference Classes.  See the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137199/what-is-the-significance-of-the-new-reference-classes

Answer (score 0):

Report as bug on r-devel so John Chambers can fix it.