# R testing for reference classes

Tags: r, reference-class

Is there a quick and dirty way to test whether an instance is from a reference class?

The standard R object tests yield the following - but nothing that seems to exclusively mark a reference class.

```
classy <- setRefClass('classy',
    fields = list(
        count = 'numeric'
    ),
    methods = list(
        initialize = function( data=NULL ) {
            .self$data <<- data
        }
    )
)

instance <- classy$new() # instantiation

isS4(instance) # TRUE
mode(instance) # "S4"
typeof(instance) # "S4"
class(instance) # [1] "classy" attr(,"package") [1] ".GlobalEnv"
dput(instance) # new("classy", .xData = <environment>)
str(instance) # 
# Reference class 'classy' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 fields
#  $ count: num(0) 
#  and 13 methods, of which 1 are possibly relevant:
#    initialize
```

Comment: Repeat after me: "I [will not call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137199/what-is-the-significance-of-the-new-reference-classes) Reference Classes `R5`"

Comment: Repeat after me "r5 is a perfectly valid abbreviation for a long name"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 inherits(instance, "envRefClass")
# should return [1] TRUE
```

This is found in the "Inheritance" section of `help(ReferenceClasses)`. And I suspect that John Chambers might object to calling this "dirty".

Apropos Hadley's comment, `is` is documented to behave mostly the same as `inherits` but has the added capacity to recognize conditional inheritance:

```
is(instance, "envRefClass")
#TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks - really appreciated - while JC may object to the "dirty" label, you must admit it is different to the other ways in which objects are inspected/tested in R. It all adds to the delightful quirkiness of R.

Comment: I think using is is slightly more canonical for s4 based classes

Comment: Oh, yeah. The mixture of naming conventions and acceptable data types to grouping arguments are a never ending source of errors on my part. OTOH, I would not be surprised to see an `isRefClass` function appear at some point.