# Is slicing copy-on-modify in R?

Tags: r, slice, copy-on-write

It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source) that `R` use copy-on-modify when assigning a variable to a new one, including passing parameter to a function.

However, does slicing (`vector`, `list`, `data frame`) create a new object, of the same type, that contains oopies of the subset of the original object, or is the elements store in the new object a copy of the original one or just a copy-on-modify reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex topic. You should start with reading about the [NAMED mechanism](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#index-NAMED).

If you run the following, you see that there is no copy of the list elements (because lists are basically pointers to their elements):

```
> a <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> 
> b <- a[1:2]
> .Internal(inspect(b)) 
@0x000000001327e5b8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(3)] (len=2, tl=0)
  @0x00000000136f6b60 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @0x00000000136f6b28 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
> 
> 
> c <- a[1:2]
> .Internal(inspect(c)) 
@0x000000001327e678 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(3)] (len=2, tl=0)
  @0x00000000136f6b60 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @0x00000000136f6b28 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
> 
> b[1] <- 6
> .Internal(inspect(b)) 
@0x000000001327e6f8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(1)] (len=2, tl=0)
  @0x0000000013745b58 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 6
  @0x00000000136f6b28 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
> 
> .Internal(inspect(c))
@0x000000001327e678 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(3)] (len=2, tl=0)
  @0x00000000136f6b60 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @0x00000000136f6b28 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

This is different if you subset vectors.

You might also be interested in the [new reference counting mechanism](https://developer.r-project.org/Refcnt.html).

Comment: I see why `vector` are different from `list`. They store all elements in one memory chunk instead of one by one since their type are known why `vector`s are created and this can minimize fragmentation, improve locality and probably allocate less space since there is only one type to record.

Comment: It's a bit more complex since R 3.5.0 introduced ALTREP.

Comment: I just realize that this is called `shallow copy`... I also wonder, can this happens on any other container in `R` (like used-defined one)?

Comment: As long as you implement them in C/C++, you can control stuff like this. The data.table package does that.

Comment: So containers provided by R packages can actually do this? That;s cool. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting an atomic vector to a shorter one will give you a new vector. Subsetting entire vectors out of objects gives you a copy-on-modify reference. The consequence of this is that you can subset to get a new shorter list object, but it's contents will be references to the contents in the original one (with no overall memory cost) until you modify.

See [Hadley's notes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) on memory management for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Different to maybe `python`, `R` creates new objects anytime you slice one. For example:

```
> a=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> b=a[1]
> b
[1] 1
> b=7
> b
[1] 7
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This works the same for `vectors`, `lists`, or `dataframes`. Take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795783/create-reference-to-an-object) post for reference-objects in `R`.

Comment: I know that slicing always creates a new one, but is the element that is contained in the new object a copy of the original or just copy-on-modify?

Comment: maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759117/what-exactly-is-copy-on-modify-semantics-in-r-and-where-is-the-canonical-source

Answer (score 0):

When subsetting a vector, R does not perform *copy-on-modify* , but it does create another object from the one we are subsetting from. For example:

```
library(lobstr)
> x = rnorm(10)
# tracking object copy:
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0xcad0728>"
> y = x # shared binding
> ref(x, y)
[1:0xcad0728] <dbl> 

[1:0xcad0728]
# So, x and y points/refers to the same object at 0xcad0728. That is, we have a shared binding to the same object 
# Now let's subsetting:
> y = y[1:5] # no warning from tracemem(). So, no copy-on-modify behavior triggered 
# now let's check the memory addrs:
> obj_addr(x)
[1] "0xcad0728"
> obj_addr(y)
[1] "0xcd1e198"
```

As we can see, there is no signal from tracemem() function about object copying. However, **subsetting did created another object in memory**, so the name **y** does not point to *0xcad0728* anymore, but to a new object at *0xcad0728*.